# Broken monodevelop

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

Hi I wanted to upgrade my version of mono so that I would be able to use certain .Net 4 features.

I downloaded the 2.10 tarball and compiled it as per the instructions I found which seems to have gone well.

This is the output I get for:

> $mono -V
>
> Mono JIT compiler version 2.10 (tarball Sun Jan  8 11:25:36 GMT 2012)
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc and Contributors.
>   www.mono-project.com  TLS:           __thread     SIGSEGV:       altstack
>     Notifications: epoll    Architecture:  x86  Disabled:      none     Misc: 
>   softdebug     LLVM:          supported, not enabled.  GC:
>   Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)**

However, monodevelop will no longer start and I get the following output instead.

> $ monodevelop WARNING: Cannot find Mozilla directory containing
>   libgtkembedmoz.so. Some Addins may not be able to function. Please set
>   MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to your Mozilla directory. Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.**

I've tried removing and reinstalling monodevelop but that doesn't seem to have worked.

Does anyone know how I can fix this or is monodevelop incompatible with mono 2.10 as it seems to be suggested by some google search results? If that is the case, how do I revert to a previous version of mono (yes I'm a bit of a linux noob)?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 with `xfce`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If the mono-2.10 makefile contains an `uninstall` target, run `make uninstall`, that should remove what was installed. Then `sudo apt-get install mono` to install the mono version from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: For what it's worth, Ubuntu 11.10 ships with mono 2.10.

Comment: It seems that everything in Linux is broken by default, and it's our job to tweak the hell out of it in order to get things working.

Answer (score 2):

Building mono and monodevelop on top of the existing ubuntu mono installation will give you very confusing and potentially broken packages. You are best off using a [Parallel Mono Environment](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments) to build newer/beta mono things.

If you don't want to sit and build everything from source you can install my new binary packages for ubuntu as described in a [Google+ post here](https://plus.google.com/100402709180247864944/posts/AVkXcYhccZd).

As for fixing your existing installation, I would do : `apt-get install --reinstall mono libmono*`

Comment: I tried running apt-get install --reinstall mono libmono but mono 2.10 still seems to be installed. I've also tried running make uninstall @ken is there a way i can manually remove mono completely to start again?

Comment: after running my rune you get a working mono (after typing pmono). Once you cure your broken mono default install you should use it.